# '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' build script ordering

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a project where I'm using CocoaPods. As part of the CocoaPods setup, the Xcode "Build Phase" gets two Cocoapods scripts:

- `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`
- `[CP] Copy Pods Resources`

In the same project I use a script that is required to run after `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`. I can setup it up manually and it works having

- `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`
- `My Script`
- `[CP] Copy Pods Resources`

Problem is that after running `pod deintegrate` to reinstall the pods the order of script is reset to:

- `My Script`
- `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`
- `[CP] Copy Pods Resources`

As the team work on this project is big. It can happen that the script order is reset by mistake causing the CI to break.

Is there a way in the Podfile to control the order of the scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a ruby gem used by CocoaPods: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj to work with Xcode project file. So with its help it's possible to manipulate the order of build phases in your project. I did a quick testing and the following script shold do what you want:

```
#fix_build_phases.rb
require 'xcodeproj'

def main
  begin
    proj = Xcodeproj::Project.open("YourProject.xcodeproj")
    target = proj.native_targets.select { |target| target.name == "YourTarget" }.first
    phase = target.build_phases.select { |phase| phase.display_name == "MyScript" }.first
    
    idx = -1
    target.build_phases.each_with_index do |phase, index| 
        if phase.display_name == "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks"
            idx = index
        end
    end
    if idx > 0
        target.build_phases.move(phase, idx)
    end
    proj.save
  end
end

main
```

If you want to ensure the script is always at the right position after the pods are installed you will need to add it to your podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    system("(sleep 1 && ruby fix_build_phases.rb)&")
end
```

There's some delay because it didn't work immediately on post_install, probably due to Cocoapods updating the project by itself at that moment.

Comment: I changed the `post_install` to `post_integrate` and was able to get rid of the sleep:

`post_integrate do |installer|`
`system("ruby fix_build_phases.rb")`
`end`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to decide a specific order. But it's possible to use a Cocoapods feature that allows to specify User Scripts in the `Podfile`.

So if you use the `script_phase` in your `Podfile` like

```
target 'App' do
    all_your_pods

    script_phase :name => 'My Script', :script => 'echo "script"'
end
```

you get the `My Script` to be inserted after all the other `[CP]` scripts as:

- `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`
- `[CP] Copy Pods Resources`
- `[CP-User] My Script`

This solves my issue even if doesn't allow you to declare a specific ordering.